# Ansible Playbook - Install/Configure Apache Error

Tags: apache, ansible

We have to install Apache, copy configuration files, and then start and configure it to run.

Here is the playbook written thus far:

```
---
- hosts: example

tasks:
- name:Install Apache
  command: yum install --quiet -y httpd httpd-devel
- name:Copy configuration files
  command:>
  cp httpd.conf /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
- command:>
  cp httpd-vshosts.conf /etc/httpd/conf/httpd-vshosts.conf
- name:Start Apache and configure it to run
  command: service httpd start
- command: chkconfig httpd on
```

However, when I run the command: `ansible-playbook playbook.yml`, I recieve this:

```
error: ERROR! Syntax Error while loading YAML.  
The error appears to have been in '/etc/ansible/playbook.yml': line 3, column 1, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

- hosts: example
tasks:
^ here
```

I have tried messing with whitespace and re-arranging things, but I still recieve this error. I am sure it's something small I am missing here, but it is bugging me to no end! Any help would be appreciated! Thanks so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding your error message, you need to pay attention to indentation. This is how it should look like:

```
---
- hosts: example

  tasks:
    - name: Install Apache
      command: yum install --quiet -y httpd httpd-devel
    - name: Copy configuration files
      command: cp httpd.conf /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
    - command: cp httpd-vshosts.conf /etc/httpd/conf/httpd-vshosts.conf
    - name: Start Apache and configure it to run
      command: service httpd start
    - command: chkconfig httpd on
```

But this is rather an example of how **not to use** Ansible.

I assume you just started to use Ansible and want to verify things, but instead of running everything with `command` module, you should rather take advantage of native modules, like [`yum`](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/yum_module.html) or [`service`](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/service_module.html). Have a look at the examples in the linked documentation pages.

---

Also take notice that in your example some tasks have names some don't. For example these are two different tasks (the first one with a name, the seconds one without):

```
- name: Copy configuration files
  command: cp httpd.conf /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
- command: cp httpd-vshosts.conf /etc/httpd/conf/httpd-vshosts.conf
```

More appropriate naming should be:

```
- name: Copy one configuration file
  command: cp httpd.conf /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
- name: Copy another configuration file
  command: cp httpd-vshosts.conf /etc/httpd/conf/httpd-vshosts.conf
```

---

Another problem: this command will fail as there should be no `httpd-vshosts.conf` in the current directory on the target machine:

```
- command: cp httpd-vshosts.conf /etc/httpd/conf/httpd-vshosts.conf
```

You must provide the full path.

Comment: Thanks so much. It worked for me.. The problem was with the whitespace!